# Scrape From Youtube

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im trying to scrape video titles from the link in the code.

Essentially want to scroll+scrape.

My code runs, but it scrapes half of the page, and instead of scraping the remaining half, repeats the first half.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url='https://www.youtube.com/user/OakDice/videos'
driver.get(url)
content=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", last_height)
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    titles = soup.findAll('a', id='video-title')
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: As I said in your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008223/how-to-get-views-from-youtube). I don't think you want to use driver.page_source

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have is in the if loop, its possible that new_height can artificially equal last height, that's where I would look

Answer (score 0):

I would simply find the element you want to scroll to and use move_to_element

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/move_to_element-method-action-chains-in-selenium-python/

```
# get the last video element
element = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")[-1]
  
# create action chain object 
action = ActionChains(driver) 
  
# perform the operation 
action.move_to_element(element)
```

That should be enough to trigger the infinite scroll on you tube.