# How to scrape views from Youtube pages

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

My code is good for the most part

I currently get all the titles from a youtube page + do a scroll.

How would I get the number of views?

Would CSS or xPath work?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url='https://www.youtube.com/user/OakDice/videos'
driver.get(url)
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", last_height)
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
content=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
titles = soup.findAll('a', id='video-title')
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be more robust to use the YouTube API to get JSON data about the videos. You can get a list of all public videos uploaded by a given user (see for instance [YouTube API to fetch all videos on a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel)), and then you use the [videos API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) to get the statistics for each video in the playlist and get the view count from `statistics.viewCount`.

Answer (score 1):

I would loop through all the videos (parent tag ytd-grid-video-renderer)
and then pluck out the titles & counts from there.

Something like:

```
allvideos = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('driytd-grid-video-renderer')
for video in allvideos:
    title = video.find_element_by_id('video-title')
    count = video.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id='metadata-line']/span')
    print (title, count)
```

I don't have a beautiful soup solution for you, as selenium will do most of the work for you.

And a word of caution on using driver.page_source, it doesn't really return a full snapshot of the DOM, so it probably isn't doing what you think it's doing.